# Is it possible to read/write macros using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, macro

Macros are saved in the *.qgs* project file. However, looking at the [QgsProject Class](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProject.html), there is no mention of a method to read or write a macro.

Other than **dangerously** editing the *.qgs* project file, is there some other method of accessing a macro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently it is possible by using the `QgsProject.instance().readEntry()` method as shown in the following link:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/utils.py#L487

---

- To read the project macro, you can use:

  ```
  print QgsProject.instance().readEntry("Macros", "/pythonCode")[0]
  ```
- To write a project macro, you can use:

  ```
  macro = u'def openProject():\r\n\t#do something\r\n\r\ndef saveProject():\r\n\t#do something else\r\n\r\ndef closeProject():\r\n\tpass\r\n'
  QgsProject.instance().writeEntry("Macros", "/pythonCode", macro)
  ```

  [image: Written macro]

  Where:

  - `\r` is the carriage return.
  - `\n` is the new line.
  - `\t` is the horizontal tab.